# fetch from function returning a ref cursor to record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a function in a package that returns a REF CURSOR to a RECORD. I am trying to call this function from a code block. The calling code looks like this:

```
declare      
   a_record package_name.record_name; 
   cursor c_symbols is select package_name.function_name('argument') from dual;

begin 
   open c_symbols;   
   loop            
        fetch c_symbols into a_record;
        exit when c_symbols%notfound;              
   end loop;
   close c_symbols; 
end;
```

The function declaration as part of package_name looks something like this:

```
TYPE record_name IS RECORD(
      field_a       varchar2(20);
);

TYPE record_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN record_name;

FUNCTION getsymbols(argument IN varchar2) return record_cursor;
```

When I try to run the calling code block, I get the exception: PLS-00386: type mismatch found at 'EXAMPLE_SYMBOLS' between FETCH cursor and INTO variables.

What should the type of a_record be and how can I access individual elements of the record I am fetching(of type record_name)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that you think that your cursor should be fetching rows from the REFCURSOR.  It's not.  The REFCURSOR is itself a cursor, you don't use another cursor to select from it.

What your current cursor is doing is fetching a single row, with a single column, containing the result of the function call.  Which is a `record_cursor` not a `record_name`, so you get a type mismatch.

I suspect what you really want to do is something like this:

```
declare
  symbol_cursor  package_name.record_cursor;
  symbol_record  package_name.record_name;
begin
  symbol_cursor := package_name.function_name('argument');
  loop
    fetch symbol_cursor into symbol_record;
    exit when symbol_cursor%notfound;

    -- Do something with each record here, e.g.:
    dbms_output.put_line( symbol_record.field_a );

  end loop;

  CLOSE symbol_cursor;

end;
```

Comment: what if my function returns a cursor to multiple records? Is there any way to iterate over those records.

Comment: That is exactly what the above code will do -- process all the rows that can be fetched from the returned cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a `record_cursor`, so I would expect `a_record` should also be a `record_cursor`. However, it is not clear why you are returning a ref cursor anyway - why can't the function return a `record_name` type instead?

Answer (score 0):

The pl/sql block to read out the ref cursor looks a bit strange to me. Oracle might not be able to match the type of your cursor `c_symbols` with the type `package_name.record_cursor`.

Suggestion:

- change the declaration of `c_symbols` to "`c_symbols package_name.record_cursor`"
- replace the statement "`open c_symbols`" with "`c_symbols := package_name.function_name('argument')`"

As long as the called function really does return a cursor, that should work.
Else, you might want to post actual source code.